# Why does a scene take a scene manager as a parameter?

Tags: python, pygame, scene, fsm

I'm having problems understanding a game scene manager (FSM) in pygame that I try to replicate from this website: https://nicolasivanhoe.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/game-scene-manager-in-python-pygame/

I'll copy the code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
 
# Modules
import pygame, sys
 
class Director:
    """Represents the main object of the game.
 
    The Director object keeps the game on, and takes care of updating it,
    drawing it and propagate events.
 
    This object must be used with Scene objects that are defined later."""
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Game Name")
        self.scene = None
        self.quit_flag = False
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
    def loop(self):
        "Main game loop."
 
        while not self.quit_flag:
            time = self.clock.tick(60)
 
            # Exit events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        self.quit()
 
            # Detect events
            self.scene.on_event()
 
            # Update scene
            self.scene.on_update()
 
            # Draw the screen
            self.scene.on_draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
 
    def change_scene(self, scene):
        "Changes the current scene."
        self.scene = scene
 
    def quit(self):
        self.quit_flag = True


class Scene:
     """Represents a scene of the game.
 
     Scenes must be created inheriting this class attributes
     in order to be used afterwards as menus, introduction screens,
     etc."""
 
     def __init__(self, director):
         self.director = director
 
     def on_update(self):
         "Called from the director and defined on the subclass."
 
         raise NotImplementedError("on_update abstract method must be defined in subclass.")
 
     def on_event(self, event):
         "Called when a specific event is detected in the loop."
 
         raise NotImplementedError("on_event abstract method must be defined in subclass.")
 
     def on_draw(self, screen):
         "Se llama cuando se quiere dibujar la pantalla."
 
         raise NotImplementedError("on_draw abstract method must be defined in subclass.")

class SceneHome(Scene):
    """ Welcome screen of the game, the first one to be loaded."""
 
    def __init__(self, director):
        Scene.__init__(self, director)
 
    def on_update(self):
        pass
 
    def on_event(self):
        pass
 
    def on_draw(self):
        pass
 
def main():
    dir = Director()
    scene = SceneHome(dir)
    dir.change_scene(scene)
    dir.loop()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
```

In the main function a director object and a scenehome object are instantiated. I understand that. Then it calls the method change_scene and passes the scenehome object. But I can't understand why a director object is a parameter inside the SceneHome class. It seems it does nothing. It looks to me as a circular call, but I don't know what it does. Why does it need a director inside the Scene class?

Answer (score 0):

The Director class is acting as your main game loop while letting the scenes handle all the logic within their own event and update methods. Which means to change scenes from a scene class to another, you'd need a reference to the director object to call self.director.change_scene(new_scene).